# the set of $C_0(X,\Bbb Z)$,where $X$ is a connected,locally compact non comapct Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected locally compact non-compact Hausdorff space,then $C_0(X,\Bbb Z)=0$.

My question is :if $X$ is a connected compact Hausdorff space,can we have the same conclusion?

Comment: Is the map taking every element of $X$ to $1$ a member of $C_0(X,\Bbb Z)$?

Comment: no,it does not vanish at infinity

Comment: It **is** supported on a compact set.

Comment: $C_0(X,\Bbb Z)$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:X\to \Bbb Z$ "vanishing at infinity":for each $\epsilon > 0$,there is compact subset K of X such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all x in X\K.If f =1,$|f(x)|$ is not less than $\epsilon$ .

Comment: OK, so the constant function $1$ **is** an element of $C_0(X,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: If $X\setminus K$ is empty then we dont need to worry whether the epsilon inequality holds, because it is automatically true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is connected, and $f: X \to \Bbb Z$ is continuous, then $f[X]$ being connected and the only non-empty connected subspaces of $\Bbb Z$ being singletons, $f$ is constant.

Now, if $f$ must vanish at infinity, it also means there is a compact $K$ such that $f \restriction_{X\setminus K}$ obeys $|f(x)|<1$ there, ergo is $0$ outside $K$.

So if $X$ is not compact, $K =X$ is impossible and the only possible $f$ is $0$ ($0$ on the non-empty outside so $0$ inside too, by being a constant).

If however $X$ *is* compact, any constant map is compactly supported ($K=X$ is allowed) and $C_0(X,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, all constant maps.